# ajax data.success block of code not be execute(variable value)

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have big problem in regrading ajax request .if the ajax request success i want to set variable value as 1 if not successes it remaining the as 0 .but my program is not working properly .what is problem and how to solved is problem?

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function() {
   temp = 0;
  $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {

    var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();

    //ot_array.push([emp_no,ot_hours]);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'otrequset_action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action:'add_ot',emp_no : emp_no, ot_hours:ot_hours},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        if(data.success)
        {
         swal("Good job!", "OverTime Request Send Successfully!", "success");
         temp = 1;
         dataTable.ajax.reload();  
        }
      }
    });  
  });
  alert(temp);//data.success alert display but value is still 0  
  if (temp == 1) {
$.ajax({
      url: 'otrequset_action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action:'add_comment'},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
        if(data.success)
        {  
         dataTable.ajax.reload();
        }
      }
    });
}
     swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function() {
   temp = 0;
  $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {

    var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();

    //ot_array.push([emp_no,ot_hours]);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'otrequset_action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action:'add_ot',emp_no : emp_no, ot_hours:ot_hours},
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {
         swal("Good job!", "OverTime Request Send Successfully!", "success");
         temp++;
         dataTable.ajax.reload();
           if (temp == 1) {
           $.ajax({
              url: 'otrequset_action.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: { action:'add_comment'},
              dataType:"json",
              success:function(data)
              {
                if(data.success)
                {  
                 dataTable.ajax.reload();
              }
             }
          });
        }  
    }
   });  
});

   swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of data.success if condition in success function of first ajax request. Are you setting it up in php code and returning back?

```
success:function(data)
      {
        if(data.success)
        {
         swal("Good job!", "OverTime Request Send Successfully!", "success");
         temp = 1;
         dataTable.ajax.reload();  
        }
      }
```

i don't think you need that if condition. Remove that condition and then try.

Moreover create an error function for handling not success cases.

Comment: first ajax request send data in multiple time.if first ajax request send data send 1 or more time i want send second ajax request only one time.that is i try to do

Comment: i try remove if(data.success) condition .but still not solve my problem

Comment: Ok. You need to wrap you second ajax request in a function and call place that inside if condition of first ajax request. As what may be happening now that temp value is being evaluated before your first ajax request completes the request and sets the temp value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function() {
    temp = 0;
    $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
        var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'otrequset_action.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { action:'add_ot',emp_no : emp_no, ot_hours:ot_hours},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    swal("Good job!", "OverTime Request Send Successfully!", "success");

                    if (temp != 1) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'otrequset_action.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { action:'add_comment'},
                            dataType:"json",
                            success:function(data) {
                                if(data.success) {
                                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    temp = 1;
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        });
  });

  swal({title: "No data entering?",text: "Not set the overtime hours !",type: "warning"});
});
```

Ajax will execute success function only when the request is successful (which means success will be executed after a delay). But the remaining code will run even though ajax is not complete (Asynchronous execution). By the time you print it or use it, it will still be 0;

Comment: not i need run second ajax request in single time .otherwise it okay.

Comment: if rum in inside multiple comment add in single approval process

Comment: Then, call second ajax inside success of first one. But check 'if (temp != 1)' before calling second ajax. Set temp as 1 inside success of first ajax.